# Apache ActiveMQ Classic 5.18 with Java 8 JMS clients

Tags: activemq-classic

[Apache ActiveMQ Classic 5.18](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5018001-release) product requires Java 11 to be running on both the JMS client and the broker.
We have some clients that cannot be upgraded from Java 8 to Java 11 yet but we would like to upgrade the brokers to 5.18.

Will the older versions of the ActiveMQ Classic JMS clients running on Java 8 (e.g. 5.11) continue working with the latest version of the broker?  May be some additional configuration needs to be done on a broker to provide compatibility with the old clients?

I couldn't find any official documentation from Apache that would cover this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.x should be backwards compatible with earlier client releases. If it isn't then it would be considered a bug that would be fixed.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the answer. You've mentioned on other topic that you are contributing the project. May be you can add this clarification on some official activeMQ manual or faq or release notes? This would  be really helpful. Thank you.